# How to draw multiple lines on a face image (facial graph) in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, graph, line, webcam

I would like to draw facial graph on a face captured by OpenCV using a webcam (a sample image is attached for a better understanding).

I have the node locations and I would like to draw a graph on a face. I want to use "CV2.line". But, the problem is that I need to repeat this code for every line that I want to draw. The total number of lines is 167.

Is there any better way to do that without repeating "CV2.line" code?

Please note that this is not a complete graph. Every node is connected to several specific nodes. So, For loop is not helpful here.

I tried networkx library. Unfortunately, networkx is not able to put the graph on a frame captured by OpenCV.

[image: example image]

Comment: What is the problem with `cv2.line()` for every point combination?

Comment: I need to draw 167 lines, but I don't want to repeat "cv2.line" 167 times. I thought there might be a better method.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/da5/tutorial_py_drawing_functions.html) take a look at "Note" after polylines function:
"cv.polylines() can be used to draw multiple lines. Just create a list of all the lines you want to draw and pass it to the function. All lines will be drawn individually. It is a much better and faster way to draw a group of lines than calling cv.line() for each line."